# iptables mangling in INPUT chain instead of PREROUTING

Tags: iptables

I followed this tutorial in order to ensure that responses are sent back along the same interface that the initiating connection came in on.

https://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2019/03/linux-policy-based-routing/

Its done using these iptables rules:

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i eth1 -j MARK --set-mark 1
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i eth1 -j CONNMARK --save-mark
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
```

Why doesn't this work if the marks are set on the INPUT chain?

Also is there any way to just use CONNMARK or must the first MARK be made and then copied from the packet to the connection?

*I am using the second connection, eth1, to provide access to the SSH daemon via a static IP. Before I had come across the aforementioned link, the default route was set to a gateway on eth0.
I was trying to debug ssh connection attempts by using separate invocations of `tcpdump` for both interfaces and I could see incoming SSH connection attempts on eth1 but I couldn't see any return packets on eth0. I had no firewall on and no iptables entries. If the tables were dropped somewhere, any idea why that would be? How could I debug such an occurrence? Thanks.*

After much googling, it appears that the "rp_filter" is most likely the culprit and if so I could have debugged this with "log_martians":
https://www.theurbanpenguin.com/rp_filter-and-lpic-3-linux-security/

This *may* also explain why the iptables rule needed to be in PREROUTING and not INPUT. Perhaps the dropping of the packets due to rp_filter was happening after PREROUTING?